# Python Переопределение родительского метода

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование

Есть стандарная процедура наследования:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._subconstructor()
    def _subconstructor(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
```

Возможно ли в данном случае переопределить поведение метода `_subconstructor` из класса `Child` не переопределяя сам `__init__` метод родительского класса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Опишите метод который хотите переопределить в наследнике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Но уже решился вопрос. Не понимал, почему не работает переопределение в дочернем классе. Оказалось, пропущена буква в имени метода. Хотел удалять вопрос, но, раз уж вы дали ответ, может, это кому-то понадобится.